# How to quickly open a view controller without executing it's processes?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have to show various folders which contain a heavy amount of images and videos , but when I click on the folder it takes few seconds to load which seems like it's lagging or hanging ...

I wanna open view controller first and then show the process of loading....
How to do that ???

Comment: try to start load in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this problem by using **SDWebImage** for problem of photos or images loading...

```
myimageview.sd_setImage(with: imageURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "empty_image_icon"))

//imageURL is URL of image.
//empty_image_icon id the default image which will show during process.
```

Comment: for refreshing purpose u can add your code in         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+0.1, execute: {

Answer (score 4):

you can load data in background like this

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   // load data here
}
```

after that need to load UI in main thread

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            // show data here
        }
```

Comment: it's still taking some time to load images...which seems like the app is lagging

Answer (score 1):

Fetch data in `viewWillAppear()` method not in `viewDidLoad()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch your data/media in `viewDidAppear()` method and **start animating your loading indicator in `viewDidLoad()`** method.

If you load data in `viewWillAppear()` than your `viewController` take a time with few second.

Answer (score 1):

You can call your fetching data function after your view created. The **viewDidAppear()** method is working after your view created but also, this method works whenever the view you create is visible on the screen so it could not be the best solution for every case. It means that, your data could be fetching unnecessarily. For example, **viewDidAppear()** method is working whenever you change your view controller and come back that screen again or switch your application or your app comes foreground.

Therefore, using **dispatchQueue** or **SDWebImage** library could be your answer.